# How to check if the row in mysql have received any update to the existing table?

Tags: php, mysql, notifications, sql-update

I have a table in mysql and two web pages 1)admin.php 2)student.php. in admin.php web page he inserts records of students.

```
$sql = "insert into student_data values('$p_id','$p_name','$p_surname','$p_email','$address','$circle','$p_cont','$loc' ,'$user_p','$pass_p','$title')";
             $data = mysql_query($sql,$conn);

             if($data)
             {
             echo $p_name ." account created";
             }
             else
             {
echo "insertion not successful"; echo mysql_error();
```

and in the second page i.e. student.php  these records are retrieved

```
<?php include"config.php"; 
                $sqli = mysql_query("select * from student_data where p_id='$name_perm'",$conn);
                while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sqli))

                {
                echo '<div class="gallerycontainer">';
                    echo '<table>';

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img height="120" width="200" src="data:image;base64,'.$rows['Image']. '"> <span><img height="240" width="400" src="data:image;base64,'.$rows['Image']. '" /></td>';
            echo '<td>'.$rows['p_name'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$rows['p_surname'].'</td></tr>';
            echo '</table>';
            echo '</div>';
                }
```

in a table format and students can see all the records. this is just an example.

now what I want is that, student wants to update his information so, HE REQUESTS ADMIN TO DO THE CHANGES. in student.php there is update section and he fills out the form and submits it.

ON THE ADMIN SIDE> when admin logs in, he gets a notification that there is a update request from student side. he reviews it and do the necessary change.

for now, I made a table called update_request , students fills the form and insert the record in those table. there is already stack of updates received by students and just want the admin to be notified that, a new record has been inserted and this is the record, kindly do the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll answer here.

Why not add a status column to your update_request table? Example : If you add a new record to update_request, the status is 0 or pending, when an admin logins you retrive all records that are status 0. When the admin treats the request, you update the record to status 1 or completed.

Comment: You mean to say that, student.php will insert the update_request table and there will be a column called status. When the data is entered from student's side, the status is set to 0 by default. and on admin side, the query is fired where status =0; right? and when admin gets all the records, he does the changes accordingly and by then the status column will update its value by 1. I hope I understood correctly.

Comment: Yes that's it. You retrieve all the status 0 rows to see the pending requests,  and update the row to 1 when the request is treated.